# menu hover transition effect left to right css

Tags: css

I have used transition property to slide the mouse over background image from top to bottom.

css:

```
a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

How to change the transition effect from left to right?

Comment: Can you put HTML and rest of CSS related to the problem. If you are changing `top` to get image from top to bottom, so to get from left to right, just change `left`

Comment: We don't need the transitions. We need the rest of the css...

Comment: Please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uWC93/. It's not working properly. I just given the html and css code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

css:

```
.a {
    background:url(http://a.static.trunity.net/images/132364/500x0/scale/butterfly-2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}

.a:hover {
    background-position:400px top;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s linear;
}
```

you can see it work on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bSyvP/1/